# Rails 5 Collection Select Not Saving ID / Select Option Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, collection-select

I am making a rails app for managing graphic design jobs. In the app, a designer has_many jobs, and each job belongs_to a designer. Seems simple enough.

The problem is the customer_id is not saving when creating a new job through the job form using the collection select.

Note - the ID is present in the collection select when I inspect using Chrome (see screenshot). The ID is just not saving for some reason.

[image]

To solve this problem, I have tried the following: 
1. Hidden field in job form
2. attr_accessor in model
3. required params in controller (bottom method)

Nothing has worked so far, and I don't know why.

Would appreciate any insight you might have.

Best,

Dan

---

Here is the code:

CUSTOMER MODEL (has many jobs)

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
  attr_accessor :customer_id #this has to be :customer_id, not just :id (fixed the option values not displaying in 
  #collection_select) 
end
```

JOBS MODEL (belongs to customer)

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord

  # Only need optional: true on the belongs_to side of the association, not the has_many side. 
  belongs_to :customer, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer

  has_many :notes, as: :noteable
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :user

end
```

JOBS CONTROLLER

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# Before filter - check if user authenticated. If not, redirect to log in page.
before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    # we aren't building an API, so no need to have users/4/jobs work at all! 
    # if admin == true @jobs - Job.all 
    # else 
    #@user = current_user
    #@jobs = @user.jobs
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @job = Job.new

  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @customer = @job.customer_id
    # Grab the current user ID and populate the @job.user_id
    @job.user_id = current_user.id


    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save  
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Job was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:title, :body, :customer_id )
      #params.require(:customer).permit(:customer_id)
    end
end
```

JOB FORM

```
<%= form_with(model: job, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if job.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% job.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :job_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body, id: :job_body, size: "120x30" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field" >
    <%= form.label :customer %>
    <%= form.collection_select :customer, Customer.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => '-- Select a Customer --'} %>
    <%#= form.hidden_field :customer_id, value: @job.customer_id %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => @job.customer_id %>
  </div>

  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id %>

   <div class="field">
          <%#= form.label :user_id %>
  <%#=  form.text_field :user_id %>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

DB SCHEMA

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20190205062652) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email_address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "customer_id"
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_customer_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_user_id"
  end
```

ROUTES

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :customers
  devise_for :users

  resources :jobs do
    resources :customers
    resources :tasks
  end

    resources :tasks do
      resources :notes
    end
    resources :jobs do
      resources :notes

    end

    #This needs to be here, otherwise error (as notes resource didn't exist on its own)
    resources :notes


    resources :users do
      resources :jobs
    end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html


  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "jobs#index"
  end
  unauthenticated :user do
    devise_scope :user do 
      get "/" => "devise/sessions#new"
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT - Here is the server log entry for a POST to /jobs for Jobs#Create

```
Started POST "/jobs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-05 16:21:46 -0800
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tzPFtpJ3NJZmFF4/X7NyXmGwfrv1jqGaiIbQirM8AEIJqqddrLPdo20AWhR4McOlI8TKRCsELfJnh+busfi1hA==", "job"=>{"title"=>"aaa", "body"=>"aaa", "customer_id"=>"", "user_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Job"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :user_id
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "aaa"], ["body", "aaa"], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:21:46.350382"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:21:46.350382"], ["user_id", 6]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/jobs/49
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
```

PARAMS POSTED TO CONTROLLER

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tzPFtpJ3NJZmFF4/X7NyXmGwfrv1jqGaiIbQirM8AEIJqqddrLPdo20AWhR4McOlI8TKRCsELfJnh+busfi1hA==", "job"=>{"title"=>"aaa", "body"=>"aaa", "customer_id"=>"", "user_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Job"}
```

EDIT: HTML PAGE SOURCE CODE FOR NEW JOB FORM

```
<p class="notice"></p>
       <p class="alert"></p>

    <h1>New Job</h1>

<form action="/jobs" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7i4b/dij53rntbjpYnzIvH2lv+sCzdyQ+B7U6fYEeAlQt3kW5mcOT+yhvMJF/nlHP9ELFNxHUPgXH+KN9MDNzw==" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_title">Title</label>
    <input id="job_title" type="text" name="job[title]" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="job_body">Body</label>
    <textarea id="job_body" name="job[body]" cols="120" rows="30">
</textarea>
  </div>

<div class="field" >
    <label for="job_customer">Customer</label>
    <select name="job[customer_id]"><option value="">-- Select a Customer --</option>
<option value="1">Nathan Wawruck </option>
<option value="2">Martin Jenkins</option>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Job" data-disable-with="Create Job" />
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/jobs">Back</a>
```

EDIT - RAILS CONSOLE - ABLE TO SAVE A CUSTOMER ID FOR A JOB

```
irb(main):007:0> **j = Job.last**
  Job Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY "jobs"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Job id: 62, title: "aaa", body: "aaa", created_at: "2019-02-07 03:27:17", updated_at: "2019-02-07 03:27:17", user_id: 6, **customer_id: nil**>
irb(main):008:0> **j.customer_id = 2**
=> 2
irb(main):009:0> **j.save**
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "jobs" SET "updated_at" = $1, "customer_id" = $2 WHERE "jobs"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2019-02-07 03:27:45.317996"], [**"customer_id", 2**], ["id", 62]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
=> **true**
irb(main):010:0> **j**
=> #<Job id: 62, title: "aaa", body: "aaa", created_at: "2019-02-07 03:27:17", updated_at: "2019-02-07 03:27:45", user_id: 6, **customer_id: 2**>
irb(main):011:0>
```

Comment: Can you show what is posted to the controller? Check the logfile, it will also log the posted parameters.

Comment: From the html view on that last edit, it looks fine. Show an updated log when you submit that form (the log shown is old, it has the user_id which is not on your view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you fill a field called `customer` and a hidden field `customer_id`.

Remove the hidden-field, you set it to `@job.customer_id` which is always nil for a new job, so you will always be saving nil. The `customer` field will be rejected by the strong parameters.

Adapt the view as follows:

```
<div class="field" >
    <%= form.label :customer %>
    <%= form.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => '-- Select a Customer --'} %>
  </div>
```

[EDIT]

Looking at your repository I can see that

- you had more hidden fields in your view code, effectively still blanking the `customer_id`
- in your controller you also set the `customer_id = params[:customer_id]`, effectively blanking the customer-id again

Fix those two and you are good to go. I created a PR so you should be able to proceed now.

Comment: EDIT: Added the server logs to the bottom of the code area. Thank you for the response NathanVDA. I implemented your suggestion and it has not worked... yet.

Comment: The posted customer_id is empty. Did you rename the collection-select and removed the hidden fields as i suggested? Did you select a customer from the drop down?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I renamed the collection-select and removed the hidden fields per your recommendation. I also select a customer for the job each time before submitting the form.

Comment: Weird, from the logfile, the parameters you posted (above), it still sends `"customer_id" => ""` so somehow the form is still setting it to nil/blank --which would correspond with the hidden field. Can you show us the html that is rendered in the view of the complete form?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I added the HTML for the view form above.

Comment: From the HTML you showed, the only reason why the "customer_id" would be blank (as per your log), would be if you did not select anything. But your log also sends a blank `user_id` (the other hidden field in your code), but it is not in your html? Does the log correspond to the shown html? Or do you have javascript that interferes on submit?

Comment: Hi Nathan and Arieljuod, as a business owner moonlighting as my own Rails development team I think I will find a local Rails developer in my home city and pay them to fix this issue. I don't have any more time to troubleshoot this. I sincerely appreciate the insights you have provided and thank you for sharing your time to help me get to the bottom of this. Have a great day.

Comment: If you have the code on github, I am always willing to take a look. But a local developer is always easier to take it further.

Comment: The issue has been solved thanks to the patience and generosity of NathanVDA. To me, this shows the caliber of people in the Ruby / Rails commuity. The fact that a complete stranger is willing to go to great lengths to successfully troubleshoot an issue for someone they don't know is absolutely amazing. Thank you for your help bro, it's sincerely appreciated! -Dan H.